# How to restart my python app automatically in AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I made few changes in my botMain.py file. CodeDeploy is successful but the changes are not effective in the app. So, I edited my RunMyBot.sh file but still there's no change.

appspec.yml

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/mybot
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/RunMyBot.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

RunMyBot.sh (new)

```
#!bin/bash

sudo /usr/bin/pm2 restart myBot
nohup python3 botMain.py & /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &
```

RunMyBot.sh (old)

```
serverfile="/lib/systemd/system/mypythonservice.service"
echo "[Unit]" > $serverfile
echo "Description=My Python Service" > $serverfile
echo "After=multi-user.target" >> $serverfile

echo "[Service]" >> $serverfile
echo "Type=idle" >> $serverfile
echo "ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/mybot/botMain.py" >> $serverfile
echo "Restart=on-failure" >> $serverfile

echo "[Install]" >> $serverfile
echo "WantedBy=multi-user.target" >> $serverfile
cat $serverfile

sudo chmod 644 /lib/systemd/system/mypythonservice.service

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl enable mypythonservice.service
```

The same server file script is in my **instance user data** also so I removed it from RunMyBot.sh

Answer (score 2):

Before you deploy new version of your app, you have to **stop your existing** `nohup`. You could do this by adding [ApplicationStop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html#appspec-reference-server) section to your `appspec.yml`.

I think the old setup was better, albeit seemingly more difficult to setup at first. With the old setup you would just `restart` your daemon.

Comment: I don't think the old setup was working. Only when I used nohup command later in cli, the application was running forever. But I didn't remove the daemon script. Now,I have added the following code in script for ApplicationStop - 

`#!bin/bash
nohup_id = ps -ef |grep nohup
kill -9 $nohup_id
`
But it is still not working

Comment: @DeadPool Do you have any logs? Why it does not work? Any errors?

Comment: the deployment status is shown as succeeded so there are no errors. I don't know how to check logs in codedeploy. Even if deployment is successful, I am not sure if it is taking my new code into consideration or my old working code.

Comment: @DeadPool you have to login to the instance and check from inside.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **BeforeInstall** hook to stop the running services and then deploy your new code in VM. After then, you can start your services.

AppSpec example : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file.html